# Access keys in a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in python like the following:

```
hist_list = [{'argument1': 1, 'argument2': 2}, {'argument3': 3, 'argument4': 4}, {'argument5': 5, 'argument6': 6}]
```

with all the keys and values being different.

Now, I want to access all the keys of all the dictionaries in a for loop but when I try this code:

```
for h in hist_list: 
    print h.keys()
```

I get only the keys of the first dictionary. Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to make it a single list?

Comment: Your code prints out all the keys: http://ideone.com/VQ2XUO

Comment: this worked for me using python 2.7.12. this is another way to do the same thing: `[h.keys() for h in hist_list]`

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`itertools` to the rescue. You can chain the dictionaries (which iterate their keys) and get the keys.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> hist_list = [{'argument1': 1, 'argument2': 2}, {'argument3': 3, 'argument4': 4}, {'argument5': 5, 'argument6': 6}]
>>> for key in itertools.chain.from_iterable(hist_list):
...     print(key)
... 
argument1
argument2
argument3
argument4
argument5
argument6
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided successfully prints all the keys in a divided fashion. The output looks something like this,

```
['argument2', 'argument1']
['argument4', 'argument3']
['argument6', 'argument5']
```

---

It seems like you wish to merge all these lists into a single list, you can do something like this,

```
keys = []
for h in h_list:
    keys.extend(h.keys())
```

Here is a small tutorial on [list.extend()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm).